# Good indicator applet for disk quota usage?

Tags: unity, indicator, quota

I've set up quotas on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS for a desktop that has multiple non-geek users.  Unfortunately, they hit quotas without much notice or visibility.

Is there a good quota indicator for unity?  All the ones I could find were device size/usage indicators (e.g. /dev/sda1) having nothing to do with quotas.

Comment: Well, as far as actually implementing quotas, that might be too big of a project, but implementing simple scripts to keep track of disk usage and send notification when it's over certain percentage - that can be done. I can even implement this feature into one of my indicators - the Udisks Indicator, maybe you've come accross it. Could you lay out what exactly you expect a program to do ?

Comment: No, not implementing quotas.  "I've set up quotas...".  I want to display the status of the quota, e.g. what the `quota` command outputs.  I could use one of the many applets that display the output from an arbitrary command, but I was hoping there was something slicker.